# CSS fit background image inside div on fixed height and width without cropping image content and take full width

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How to fit background image inside div on fixed height and width without cropping image content and take full width.
Render size of the image is `318px width x 422px height` it should contain inside a `290px x 310px` container without loosing image content and image should not look stretched.

I have tried **background-size: cover;** // here it crops image content

**background-size: contain** // here there is extra white space is created

```
  .card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 290px;
    height: 542px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

.bg-img {
    background-image: url("url");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 310px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
  }



<div class="card">
      <div class="bg-img" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcpqsowh/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dreambold/nowq2f9v/11/ Please have a look at this. It's the best result you can get

Comment: How do you expect your image not to lose content if proportions of image and container do not match?

Comment: `inside a 290px x 310px container` What's this element? Div.card or what?

Comment: thanks ! but height of image should not exceed  310px need to add content below image.

Comment: @IvanBeliakov any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you want your image to perfectly fit your card, you need to change the dimensions of the card :)

Comment: Is you card content supposed to be displayed over the image? Or do you need the image to be in the top part of the card and have empty space in the bottom for other content?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dreambold/nowq2f9v/50/ Please have a look at this, it's a little stretched, but if it works for you, it would be great

Comment: @DreamBold better, i have tried this but need not to stretch image

Comment: @IvanBeliakov what should be idel dimension of card to fit the image ?

Comment: I don't think you can find a better solution

Comment: card content display below image. image should not exceed 320px height, else it will throw below content out.

Comment: Your current container is 290px x 310px. One dimension has to be changed. Which one do you want to keep the same, height or width?

Comment: If height is more important, set the width of the card to 233px.